# Building Twilio Phone Company Directory

Tags: php, api, twilio, voice

I'm trying to implement the following tutorial from Twilio:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/companydirectory

I'm currently stuck at the following step:

***You would assign this scripts URL to your incoming phone number in Twilio. When a call is received at that phone number, Twilio makes a request to this script.***

How can I make a PHP file available for execution online so that Twilio can make a request to this file?

Thanks, Eyad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

We're a big fan of the product [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) which allows you to tunnel through from a public URL to your application running on your computer.

Check out this post about [the benefits of ngrok](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/09/6-awesome-reasons-to-use-ngrok-when-testing-webhooks.html) and this post which walks through [getting started with ngrok](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2013/10/test-your-webhooks-locally-with-ngrok.html).

Comment: Indeed. I managed to get this done using both XAMPP and ngrok. I now troubleshooting some mysql-related issues on my PHP script. Will you be able to help?

Comment: If I answered your original question it's best to mark this as correct and then ask a new question and people will be able to find that easier and help answer.